JavaScript en Vscode no me completa las palabras y tampoco me cambia de color las variables
Al momento de escribir console.log no me completa los paréntesis y tampoco lo cambia de color ,lo deja en color blanco,si funciona pero es más trabajoso estar poniendo paréntesis y no ver cuáles son las funciones porque no cambia de color al momento de ponerlas(mi computadora es una Mac),por favor alguien que me pudiera ayudar


¿Y tenés la extensión (plugin) de resaltado de sintaxis de JavaScript en VS Code? Recordá que VS Code es un simple editor de código, no un IDE.

Si tengo “Flatland Monokai Theme” es que como soy nuevo en esto,estoy pasando unos cursos y a mi profesor no le sucede lo mismo que a mí y trabajamos en el mismo sistema operativo

Tener un "theme" solo te pone los colores en la sintaxis, no te autocompleta nada. Si estás en un curso, pregunta a la persona que lo imparte que plugins está usando y cual es su configuración de vscode para que tu tengas el mismo entorno.
